# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 'accounts' WHERE role = 'engineer' getting the total number of rows using symfony1.4

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4

Hi i have a problem in getting all the data from the table accounts, I want to get the total number of data's from the table accounts using WHERE. Let's say from the table accounts where role = engineer. all the total number of rows from the field role = engineer will get. Im using symfony framework on this

Here's my controller below

```
<?php
class spFindRoleDetailAction extends sfAction{

  function preExecute(){
  }

  public function execute($request){

        $this->setLayout('spLayout');
    $this->setTemplate('sp/roleDetail');

        $role = $request->getParameter('ro');
        $this->roleDetail = AccountTable::getInstance()->getRoleDetail($role);
        $this->roleCount = AccountTable::getInstance()->getCountDetail($role);

    }
}
```

Model query

```
 public function getCountDetail($role){
                return $this->createQuery('a')
                ->where('a.role = ?', $role)
                ->execute();
     }
```

and my module templates view code here

```
<div id="search-by-role-detail" data-role="page">
    <div role="main">
    <ul data-role="listview">  
      <li>
        <a href="<?php echo url_for('@find-sp-role-page'); ?>" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-nav-l center"> 
          <h1>エンジニア<span class="header-result-count">(<?php echo $roleCount->count(); ?>)</span></h1>
        </a>
      </li>
            <?php if(isset($roleDetail)): ?>
            <?php foreach($roleDetail as $role): ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php echo $role->getSlug(); ?>"class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-list-r" data-transition="slide">
                    <?php if($role->getLogo() == NULL): ?>
                        <div class="middle v-image">
                            <img class="image-user" src="/images/sp/sample.png">
                        </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="middle v-image">
                            <img class="image-user" alt="<?php echo $role->getName(); ?>" src="http://img.creww.me/uploads/account/logos/<?php echo $role->getLogo(); ?>">
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
          <div class="middle v-list">
            <h3><?php echo $role->getName(); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo $role->getOverview(); ?></p>
          </div>     
        </a>
      </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The one in the H1 tag there is a count in there, How will i able to get the total number of rows in it. Im using there a `<?php echo $roleCount->count(); ?>` which is wrong

Anyone can help me out on this??
Any help is muchly appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that the `count()` method is wrong? Note that in the controller you use the `getRoleDetail()` method but you presented the `getCountDetail()` method from your model.

Comment: i updated my post.. the wrong part is the total number of rows will be displayed is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `count()` isn't working then you can try something like this.

```
public function getCountDetail($role)
{
   $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('[some table] a')
        ->where('a.role = ?', $role)
        ->select('COUNT(a.id)')
        ->execute(array(),Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR)
   return $q;
}
```

In this case the function will return a single number representing the number of records found.

Comment: ok i will try this how about the Doctrine_Query i will use this one?
return $this->createQuery('a') ?? is it the same?

Comment: Are you using Doctrine 1.4 or Doctrine 2.x?

Comment: using symfony 1.4 i mean that doctrine is also 1.4

Comment: It is the same if using a Doctrine_Table object. Look at this for an example http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/doctrine/1_2/en/06-Working-With-Data

Comment: your codes not working

Couldn't find class accounts

Comment: You don't need to include the square brackets. It should be name of the table. If your table class is Accounts then it would need to be Accounts. The case is important and will depend on how you defined the class name in the scheme.yml file.

Comment: can i do on this code?

 public function getCountDetail($role){
  return $this->createQuery('a')
      ->andWhere('a.role = ?', $role)
      ->count();
   }

Comment: hi your code seems to return only 1  not all the data's

Comment: Aah sorry missed adding in the $role. I've modified the answer.

Comment: oh i added that to my code seems your code will return only 1

Comment: ive got this my code is this ok?

public function getCountDetail($role){
  return $this->createQuery('a')
        ->where('a.role = ?',$role)
        ->select('COUNT(a.role)')
        ->count();
   }

Comment: You do net the ->count() as the select is returning a single value. You probably only need to add ->execute() in place of the ->count()

Comment: ahh okay so this will return all the number of rows?

Comment: Yes the number of rows with role = $role.

Comment: but how come when i tried to query on phpmyadmin the count code it is different to the the code that you are provided in?

Comment: Is your php admin query correct? Is it actually doing the same as the query above? How far off is it? Unless you've verified in some other way that the phpadmin query result is actually correct (i.e. have you manually counted the rows). Primary reason for them to be different is that the queries aren't actually the same e.g. the doctrine query filters out all softdelete rows and your phpadmin query doesn't.

Comment: my query in phpmyadmin is
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM accounts WHERE role ='engineer';
it will return all the total number of rows

Comment: Ok so are you using softdelete behaviour in Doctrine? If you are then doctrine is ignoring all the rows with deleted_at != NULL and your PHPmyadmin ignores whether the field deleted_at field is null or not.